# Classical ASP Scripting Timeout

Tags: scripting, asp-classic, timeout

Is it possible to catch a **classical ASP Scripting Timeout** and redirect to a proper self defined error page, to avoid that the user sees the runtime error page ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using IIS?  You can configure IIS to have a predefined error page.

**EDIT**

Take a look at [this site](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/80cb8d8d-8fd8-4af5-bb3b-4d11fff3ab9c.mspx?mfr=true) on configuring your error pages on IIS.  You should be able to create an error page that can display a friendly message to the user whenever timeouts occur...I know for the company I work for, we experienced SQL timeouts before recently upgrading our systems.

You can also look at [this site](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/ASP/quickref/500100code.html) for some classic ASP code to get the latest server error.

Hope this helps.

Comment: what version of IIS and what OS is IIS running on?

Comment: iis 6 on a windows 2003 server

Comment: Glad to hear it.  Take a look at the sites I just suggested...they may help you even further.